# Python: [Errno ftp error] [ Errno 111] connection refused

Tags: python, web-crawler

```
import urllib

def get_page(url):
    try:
        import urllib
        return urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    except:
        return ""

def get_next_target(seed):
    start_link = seed.find('<a href=')
    if start_link == -1:
        return 0, 0
    start_quote = seed.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = seed.find('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = seed[start_quote + 1 : end_quote ]
    return url, end_quote

def get_all_links(seed):
    links = []
    while True:
        url, remaining_page = get_next_target(seed)
        if url:
            links.append(url)
            seed = seed[remaining_page : ]
        else:
            break
    return links


def crawl_web(seed):
    tocrawl = [seed]                       
    crawled = []          
    while tocrawl:
        page = tocrawl.pop()  
        if page not in crawled:
            crawled.append(page) 
            f = urllib.urlopen(page)
            content = f.read() 
            tocrawl = tocrawl + get_all_links(content)
    print crawled

crawl_web('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_engineering')
```

I am trying to build a web crawler but the above code renders the following error:

[click here for viewing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3VQ8.png)

Please help!!

Comment: Have you tried doing any debugging? Have you tried printing the url that you are opening? How is your code supposed to handle the situation where a website is offlinenot working?

Comment: You don't have a user-agent set so wikipedia is probably deflecting your request as an obvious bot

Comment: Instead of posting an image of the error, please copy-paste the error. This will help future readers, search engines, and so on.